# JQuery .load(url, function (response, status, xhr)

Tags: jquery, html

I am having difficulties understanding and getting the expected functionality for the code I am using. As I have no experience with jQuery I am having a hard time to figure this out.

I have created a simple `.html` file where I have the code below. What I am expecting to get is the response `xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText` as you can see on the call for `error` status below. But that is actually all I am getting. No URL used is performing the `success` status. What is wrong here?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
Error response:
<div id="success"></div>
<script>
    var url ="http://www.google.ca/";
    $("#success").load(url, function (response, status, xhr) {
        if (status == "error") {
            var msg = "Sorry but there was an error: ";
            $("#success").html(msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
        } else if(status=='success') {
            $('#success').html(response);
        }
        else {alert(status)}
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

At the end of my code I want to target my tomcat home installation (http://localhost:8080/), just to know if the Tomcat is running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to make ajax call to a different domain. Ajax calls are not allowed across domains, unless you override access-controll-allow-origin header. Trying making a request to html sitting in localhost domain to test.

Comment: Hello minion, I have tested as you recommended but no success response either.. I have pointed the url to http://localhost:8080/sample/hello.jsp which gives me the same outcome ".... error: 0 error"

Comment: Yes. The same as before.

Comment: Is you html running in your server as well or is it standalone html? Remember if you are running your html in localhost and requesting resource in localhost host domain, you should not be running into an issue.

Comment: WOW! BOOM!
I read many times about the "accros domains" while trying to troubleshoot this problem but I couldn't get the point about the concept/idea of it.
Indeed sitting the test page into the same local as of my tomcat test application I get the response expected!
THANKS A LOT